# How can I implement this function in Odoo 12 or OpenERP?

Tags: python, xml, odoo, helper

I'm trying to make a conditional function for the invoices.
I know how to write but I don't know how can I implement in Odoo by code.

**My function**

```
if(country_id==base.au || country_id==base.ca || country_id==base.jp || country_id==base.li)
{
   <t t-if="o.emb_confirm_message == True">
       <strong><th t-field="o.emb_message"/></strong>
   </t>
}
```

When the invoice has any of does countries a message will appear on the report.
How can I implement this function in Odoo 12?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a fan of too much code in QWeb templates, but this should work:

```xml
<t t-set="is_for_emb_message_country"
    t-value="o.partner_id.country_id.id in [o.env.ref('base.au').id, o.env.ref('base.ca').id, o.env.ref('base.jp').id, o.env.ref('base.li').id]" />
<t t-if="o.emb_confirm_message is True and is_for_emb_message_country">
       <strong><th t-field="o.emb_message"/></strong>
</t>
```

Comment: Hi @CZoellner how can I do the same but instead of countries id, with a country group

Comment: Depends on an existing "xml id" (external id) so that you can use `ref` with it. But wouldn't it be easier to just add a boolean field to `res.country` and using that instead. The code would be smaller too, like `<t t-if="o.emb_confirm_message is True and o.partner_id.country_id.new_boolean_field is True">`.

Comment: But if there id of country group is 3 what I put?

Comment: Don't use database IDs in code. Try to get a cleaner way to fulfill your requirement.

Comment: Okey, but how can I do that? *Try to get a cleaner way to fulfill your requirement*

Comment: I've given you an alternative. Extend `res.country` with a new boolean field and use that directly like in my comment.